# Let $X$ be a metric space and let $E\subseteq X$. Let $x_0$ be a limit point of $E$. Then show the following.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $E\subseteq X$. Let $x_0$ be a limit point of $E$. Then show the following:

 a. For each $r > 0$, $B(x_0, r)$ contains infinitely many points of $E$.

 b. There exists a set $S \subseteq E$ such that $S$ is infinite and such that $x_0$ is the only limit point of $S$.

So, here's my try:

 a. By definition of limit point, $\forall r>0, \ \exists q \in B(x_0,r) \cap E \text{ and } q \neq x_0 $ Now let us define a set $S'(r) := \{q_n \ | \ q_n \in B(x_0, r/n) \cap E \text{ and } q_n \neq x_0\}$ . Now, $S'$ is well defined as $B(x_0, r/n) \subseteq B(x_0,r)$ and according to definition of limit point, we always have a $x \in B(x_0, R) \cap E$ s.t. $x\neq x_0$ and $R>0$. Now, clearly $S'(r) \subseteq E \cap B(x_0,r)$ and $S'(r)$ is infinite as $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is infinite, so for each $r>0$,  $B(x_0,r)$ has infinitely many points of $E$.

Now for part b. I want to use the result of part a. Here is what I thought:

 I will define $S \subseteq S'(r)$ for a fixed $r$ say s.t. :
$$S := \{x  \ | \ x \in S'(r) , s.t. d(q_i,q_j) = \frac{r}{2}\bigl\lvert\frac{1}{i} -\frac{1}{j}\rvert \} \ \cup \ \{x_0\} $$
Does this work ? $S$ is still infinite and hopefully it satisfies that $x_0$ is the only limit point. Please someone check my proof/sketch and give suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

For question a): What you can easily show is that $B(x_0, r)\cap E$ is non-empty and cannot be a finite set.

For question b): The idea is of course to choose, for every $n$, a point $a_n$ in $B(x_0, r_n)-\{x_0\}$, where $r_n$ is some sequence of positive numbers that tends to zero. Whether such a choice is possible depends on a version of the axiom of choice.